# Outlook Contact Properties and Active Directory / Exchange

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, outlook

Are there any references to the Active Directory attributes that Outlook uses when viewing the properties of a contact within Outlook (i.e. when you search the global address book and right click > properties)? In particular, the 'Manager' and 'Direct reports' boxes under the Organisation tab. Interested in this for syncing Active Directory with SharePoint 2010.

In Outlook, is it possible to change the properties form so that additional data from custom attributes can be shown and change existing labels (e.g. 'zip code' to 'post code')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See following link for the mapping:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140502211701/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2009/05/04/quicktip-ad-properties-mapped-to-sharepoint-profiles.aspx)

Additional Properties can be added from "Manage User Properties" in Central Administration -> Manage Service Application - > User profile service application -> Manage User Properties

The Display name can be changed from above link as well.

Comment: Can't see 'direct reports' there though. You could have a manager but report to several people.

Comment: I believe User1's Direct Reports = Those persons whose Manager = User1. There is no such property that you can Map to. This has to be derived by querying user profile. For example, UserProfile.GetDirectReports() method gives all user profiles who are direct reports to the user profile in question.